# javaFX focusHandler?

Tags: javafx, focuslistener

I am just changing from AWT to JavaFX and im wondering how to work with focus.
For Exampe: In AWT I wrote something like that:

```
Button bFocus = new Button("Focus");
bFocus.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {

        public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Having the Focus");
        }

        public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Lost the Focus");
        }
});
```

But how does it work in JavaFX? I tried many different things, but that doesnt work...

Answer (score 1):

JavaFX has an API that defines [observable properties](http://www.oracle.com/pls/topic/lookup?ctx=javase80&id=JFXBD107) with which you can register listeners and respond when they change. Almost all state that belongs to UI elements in JavaFX is represented by these properties, allowing you to register a listener that responds when they change.

So, for example, the superclass of all UI elements, [`Node`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html) has a `ReadOnlyBooleanProperty` called [`focused`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#focusedProperty), with which you can register a listener:

```
Button bFocus = new Button("Focus");
bFocus.focusedProperty().addListener((obs, wasFocused, isNowFocused) -> {
    if (isNowFocused) {
        System.out.println("Having the Focus");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Lost the Focus");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought it might be helpful to see an example which specifies the ChangeListener as an anonymous inner class like James_D mention here.

```
TextField yourTextField = new TextField();
yourTextField.focusedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>()
{
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> arg0, Boolean oldPropertyValue, Boolean newPropertyValue)
    {
        if (newPropertyValue)
        {
            System.out.println("Textfield on focus");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Textfield out focus");
        }
    }
});
```

I hope this answer is helpful!

Comment: why repeat an answer with a rather outdated pattern? If you see any advantages, please describe them :)